# anaconda subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, anaconda, github-actions

I am use Github Actions for uploading into anaconda channel. it gives an error that I can't debug. Every component is working okay but I can't find any similar error. Could you provide a hint how to debug this error?

This is meta.yaml

```
{% set version = "0.1.1rc42" %}

package:
  name: blablablabla
  version: {{ version }}

source:
  url: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/source/e/blablablabla/blablablabla-0.1.1rc42.tar.gz

build:
  noarch: python
  number: 0
  script: python -m pip install --no-deps --ignore-installed .

requirements:
  host:
    - python
    - pip
    - numpy==1.16.5
    - cython
  run:
    - python

test:
  imports:
    - blablablabla

about:
  home: https://github.com/blablablabla-author/blablablabla
  license: GPLv3
  summary: 'blablablabla'
  description: |
    blablablabla 
  dev_url: https://github.com/bowman-lab/blablablabla
  doc_url: https://pypi.org/project/blablablabla/
  doc_source_url: https://blablablabla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
```

This is the code that uploads to anaconda.

```
    conda config --set anaconda_upload yes
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y build-essential
    conda create -n myenv python=3.6
    activate myenv
    conda install --yes pip
    conda install --yes numpy cython
    conda install --yes -c conda-forge nose mdtraj  
    anaconda login --username $INPUT_ANACONDAUSERNAME --password $INPUT_ANACONDAPASSWORD
    echo $PWD
    conda build . 
    anaconda logout
```

This is the error that I get.

```
020-02-28T00:50:40.4600708Z INFO:conda_build.source:Downloading source to cache: blablablabla-0.1.1rc40.tar.gz
2020-02-28T00:50:40.4601418Z INFO conda_build.source:download_to_cache(66): Downloading source to cache: blablablabla-0.1.1rc40.tar.gz
2020-02-28T00:50:40.4602139Z INFO:conda_build.source:Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/source/e/blablablabla/blablablabla-0.1.1rc40.tar.gz
2020-02-28T00:50:40.4602871Z INFO conda_build.source:download_to_cache(80): Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/source/e/blablablabla/blablablabla-0.1.1rc40.tar.gz
2020-02-28T00:50:40.4603721Z Downloading source to cache: blablablabla-0.1.1rc40.tar.gz
2020-02-28T00:50:40.4604375Z Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/source/e/blablablabla/blablablabla-0.1.1rc40.tar.gz
2020-02-28T00:50:40.6318549Z INFO:conda_build.source:Success
2020-02-28T00:50:40.6318756Z INFO conda_build.source:download_to_cache(91): Success
2020-02-28T00:50:40.6321187Z Success
2020-02-28T00:50:41.9181877Z     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
2020-02-28T00:50:41.9184004Z      command: /opt/conda/conda-bld/blablablabla_1582851022543/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_place/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-dljojnij/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-dljojnij/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-req-build-dljojnij/pip-egg-info
2020-02-28T00:50:41.9184761Z          cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-dljojnij/
2020-02-28T00:50:41.9185124Z     Complete output (11 lines):
2020-02-28T00:50:41.9185456Z     Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-02-28T00:50:41.9187027Z       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
2020-02-28T00:50:41.9187934Z       File "/tmp/pip-req-build-dljojnij/setup.py", line 106, in <module>
2020-02-28T00:50:41.9188330Z         ext_modules=cythonize(cython_extensions),
2020-02-28T00:50:41.9189305Z       File "/opt/conda/conda-bld/blablablabla_1582851022543/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_place/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 971, in cythonize
2020-02-28T00:50:41.9189776Z         aliases=aliases)
2020-02-28T00:50:41.9190729Z       File "/opt/conda/conda-bld/blablablabla_1582851022543/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_place/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 815, in create_extension_list
2020-02-28T00:50:41.9191479Z         for file in nonempty(sorted(extended_iglob(filepattern)), "'%s' doesn't match any files" % filepattern):
2020-02-28T00:50:41.9192445Z       File "/opt/conda/conda-bld/blablablabla_1582851022543/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_place/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 114, in nonempty
2020-02-28T00:50:41.9192927Z         raise ValueError(error_msg)
2020-02-28T00:50:41.9193461Z     ValueError: 'blablablabla/info_theory/libinfo.pyx' doesn't match any files
2020-02-28T00:50:41.9193987Z     ----------------------------------------
2020-02-28T00:50:41.9221151Z ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7756204Z Extracting download
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7757038Z source tree in: /opt/conda/conda-bld/blablablabla_1582851022543/work
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7757877Z export PREFIX=/opt/conda/conda-bld/blablablabla_1582851022543/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_place
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7758325Z export BUILD_PREFIX=/opt/conda/conda-bld/blablablabla_1582851022543/_build_env
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7758673Z export SRC_DIR=/opt/conda/conda-bld/blablablabla_1582851022543/work
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7758827Z Processing $SRC_DIR
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7777905Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7778886Z   File "/opt/conda/bin/conda-build", line 11, in <module>
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7779085Z     sys.exit(main())
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7779665Z   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 469, in main
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7779865Z     execute(sys.argv[1:])
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7780417Z   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 460, in execute
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7780871Z     verify=args.verify, variants=args.variants)
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7781423Z   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/api.py", line 209, in build
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7781632Z     notest=notest, need_source_download=need_source_download, variants=variants)
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7787528Z   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 2344, in build_tree
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7787785Z     notest=notest,
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7788445Z   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 1492, in build
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7793073Z     cwd=src_dir, stats=build_stats)
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7793801Z   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 398, in check_call_env
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7794226Z     return _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ('call', *popenargs, **kwargs)
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7794783Z   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 378, in _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7795034Z     raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, _args)
2020-02-28T00:50:42.7795506Z subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/bin/bash', '-o', 'errexit', '/opt/conda/conda-bld/blablablabla_1582851022543/work/conda_build.sh']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: This doesn't look conda specific to me. `ValueError: 'blablablabla/info_theory/libinfo.pyx' doesn't match any files` - running the setup.py throws the error

Comment: How could I find exact error?